# Access Database for Links

Tags: database, ms-access, hyperlink

I am trying to create a database that can be used in my office. What I am trying to do is create a form where a user can input a link such as "www.stackoverflow.com" and it pulls up information about that link. For example, when we are reviewing documents, if we saw the link "www.stackoverflow.com" we would have to create an Alternate Text that instead would read "Stack Overflow Website" if it was being read by a screen reader.

We deal with so many links across so many documents that it can be hard for my team to be consistent document to document, person to person. So having this database would allow someone to enter the url and then it would pull up the alt text we have for it in multiple languages. I am learning and trying to figure out databases but I am not very well knowledged on how to put it all together within Access.

I would appreciate any kind of help or pushes in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the wrong forum. SA is for code helping not application building.

Comment: Gustav is right, but you can contact me... I can help you